# Sharekit - ndefined symbols for architecture i386:

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, sharekit

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_EvernoteSession", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SHK", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SHKConfiguration", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SHKFacebook", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SHKGooglePlus", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've googled a lot but can't find anithyng that works for me. I've followed the installation guide, step by step, I've triple checked that I've added all the framework needed, I read & tryed this ["symbol(s) not found for architecture i386" problem using ShareKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889940/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-i386-problem-using-sharekit) but still getting this error... Help please!

Answer (score 1):

After 12 hours of madness I realized that my folder tree was wrong. You can download file via git (very easy also for an icon pusher like me) or via browser but you have to PAY ATTENTION in have a result like:

```
Project Root
 |
 |-Submodules
   |
   |-ShareKit
      |
      |-Submodules
         |
         |-All the subfolder with files (notice that if you download it as .zip from github, the folder will be created but they are EMPTY!
```

If you have any difference from this you'll get huge & unpredictable problems!

Thanks everybody for the help.

PS: I suggest to try adding ShareKit to a new and empty project, just to get familiar with it and preserve your real project.

Answer (score 0):

First Tell Me if You have to Putted any `framework` as copy-paste ?? in most of cases this type of issue created.

Generally this Types of Error Occur when your class `.m` file is not store/putted under `Compile Sources`

In This case you need to add manually this `.m` file to `Compile Sources`

**Following step Describe how to put `.m` file in `Compile Sources` manually**

```
Select Project Form Project Manager
  |
  | 
  Targets
       |
       |
     Build Phases
          |
          |
        Compile Sources
                |
                |
        Click on '+' button and add .m file in it
```

This is Step For how to put file manually in `Compile Sources`.

**EDITE:**

I am not sure but i thinks you forget to add `CoreData.framework` first add it.
Refer This Question [How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4) for how to add **framework**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) Clean your code( press Cmd + Shift + K)

2) Quit Xcode and Restart Again

3) Ensure that SHKFacebook.m, SHKConfiguration.m etc files are added in the Build Phases and Compile Sources.

4) Ensure that all the submodules in Sharekit are downloaded...

Hope this helps...